# replacing specific values with NA using na_if

Tags: r, dataframe

My dataframe has few values as 9.969210e+36, I want to replace them with NA. It looks like

```
# A tibble: 1,308 x 3
       IMD     CRU dts       
     <dbl>   <dbl> <date>    
 1 9.97e36 9.97e36 1901-01-01
 2 9.97e36 9.97e36 1902-01-01
 3 9.97e36 9.97e36 1903-01-01
 4 9.97e36 9.97e36 1904-01-01
```

> dput(head(df))

```
structure(list(IMD = c(9.96920996838687e+36, 9.96920996838687e+36, 
9.96920996838687e+36, 9.96920996838687e+36, 9.96920996838687e+36, 
9.96920996838687e+36), CRU = c(9.96920996838687e+36, 9.96920996838687e+36, 
9.96920996838687e+36, 9.96920996838687e+36, 9.96920996838687e+36, 
9.96920996838687e+36), dts = structure(c(-25202, -24837, -24472, 
-24107, -23741, -23376), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I followed [R - Replace specific value contents with NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457877/r-replace-specific-value-contents-with-na) as

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(IMD, CRU), na_if, 9.969210e+36)
df %>% na_if(x=as.vector(df$IMD),y=9.97e36)
```

None of the above shows NA values and returns same old dataframe.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please provide at least some excerpt of the data.

Comment: In sharing an excerpt of the data, it will be helpful to share the output of `dput(head(df))` so that we can see the exact way the data is encoded, not just how it appears in the tibble representation in your question.

Comment: It could be the issue as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`na_if` works on *vectors*, not *data.frame*, thus your first attempt using `mutate` would be most correct. Furthermore, it compares *exact* values to replace with `NA`.
However, your very large values are only displayed with 15 digits; I suspect there are a lot, lot more. Therefore, no values are matched exactly to your conditional (`y`).  This is a common problem when trying to exactly compare to real values.

Also note that you are trying to compare the two values. Which is largest?

```
9.969210e+36
9.96920996838687e+36
```

You can do it quickly by:

```
df %>%> mutate(
  IMD=ifelse(IMD > 9e36, NA, IMD),
  CRU=ifelse(CRU > 9e36, NA, CRU)
)
```

or create a function as,

```
na_when_larger <- function(x, y) {
  x[x > y] <- NA
  x
}

df %>% mutate_at(vars(IMD, CRU), na_when_larger, 9.96e+36)
```

(try typing `na_if` into the console *without* parenthesis).

Comment: Thanks @MrGumble, I could recognize that precision is the issue.